# PHP only include file if variable is called

Tags: php, html, include

I figured it would be best to give an example of an issue I'm trying to resolve vs posting my code. (If you would still like the code let me know).

I'm trying to create one folder and one index.php file with multiple different sites inside that have large differences. I have localhost pointing to a Development folder in wwwroot folder. Inside the dev folder, I have one index.php, a global include folder and multiple mini php sites in more folders.

I need to setup variables for each site that point to include files. Example:

```
$html5 =  include '/global-includes/global-html5standard.php';
$email =  include '/global-includes/global-emailtemp.php';
```

Depending on what site I want to see on the index, I will call the specific variable.

```
echo $html5;
```

While having the other variables commented out.

```
//echo $email;
```

The issue is the include pulls in the content regardless. I'd like to make it only pull in if it is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your variables to just the path name.

```
$html5 = '/global-includes/global-html5standard.php';
```

Then include the variable. Instead of `echo $html5;` you'd use `include( $html5 );`

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, Thanks i don't know why i didn't think of this.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use [functions](http://php.net/functions) instead.

```
function email() {
    include('/global-includes/global-emailtemp.php');
}

function html5() {
    include('/global-includes/global-html5standard.php');
}
```

You may also want to use [include_once()](http://php.net/include_once) so the files will only be included once no matter how many times you call it.

Comment: This is something i could do as well, is there a benefit to using functions vs what Nathan suggested? And yes i will use include_once() thanks for your input.

Comment: If you only need to include one file then using a variable would be okay because you will call `include($variable)` only once.

Comment: Just a couple of really minor niggles I have... 1: `include` is a language construct not a function, it doesn't need the parentheses. 2: when including a required system file, (i.e. one you need for the script to function properly rather than one that can be allowed to fail and be caught) it's arguably better to use `require` or `require_once`. /pedant (sorry)